# (JSP) Writing UTF8 to MySQL won't work

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, jstl

I am trying to write russian characters to MySQL 5.5 using JSP (JSTL).
While it works on my own localhost, I can't get it to work on the server I rented.

It's sending the right params from a form to another page, which then shows the output correctly. This also works on the server. 
Writing/Reading to and from DB only works on my own localhost.

If I try to write to DB on the server, russian characters turn into question marks. However, I can store russian characters using phpMyAdmin, which then display correctly on my web page.

Here is my query and what I've tried so far:
Query:

```
    <sql:update dataSource="${ds}" var="updatedTable">
        INSERT INTO Question (question) VALUES (?) 
        <sql:param value="${param.questionAsked}" />
    </sql:update>
```

DBconn:

```
    <sql:setDataSource var="ds" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDBname?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8" user="secret" password="secret" />
```

Page Encoding in every JSP file:

```
    <%@page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Add this to tomcat server.xml:

```
    <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
/>
```

Uncommented the CharacterEncodingFilter in web.xml:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And altering/creating new DB's and DB tables for test with utf8:

```
CREATE TABLE `Question` (
  `questionID` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `question` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryID` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`questionID`),
  KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `question_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `Category` (`categoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I guess my problem is somewhere in the MySQL connector. I could not quite figure out how to change it since I don't have access to the config files of mysql. I requested SSH access if that helps me. I'm fairly new to such issues since I haven't been dealing with databases and especially servers for too long.

phpMyAdmin shows:

```
character set client - latin1, (session value - utf8)
character set connection - latin1, (session value - utf8)
character set database - latin1
character set results - latin1, (session value - utf8)
character set server - latin1
character set system - utf8
collation connection - latin1_swedish_ci (session value - utf8_unicode_ci)
collation database - latin1_swedish_ci
collation server - latin1_swedish_ci
```

I hope you can suggest what to do...

Comment: Thanks for your help Balus, I could figure it out by using a servlet to make sure utf8 goes in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.
Just uncommenting the CharacterEncoding filter wasn't enough.
I had to implement a filter into my webapp as well.
Heres the code:

```
package filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class CharsetFilter implements Filter {
private String encoding;

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");

    if (encoding == null)
        encoding = "UTF-8";
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Respect the client-specified character encoding
    // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
    if (null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
        request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);

    /**
     * Set the default response content type and encoding
     */
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    next.doFilter(request, response);
}

public void destroy() {
}

}
```

And don't forget it in the web.xml:

```
   <filter>
   <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>filters.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
   </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```